# Convert.ToInt64 equivalent in java

Tags: java, c#, parsing, long-integer, typeconverter

I try the following code in c# and it give me the result as follow:

```
long dec1 = Convert.ToInt64("B62FD56EFD5B375D", 16);
```

result : -531879796222753398

I am trying to do this in java, but I always get `NumberFormatException`, because there are alphanumeric inside the String. What I code in java is:

```
Long.parseLong("B62FD56EFD5B375D", 16);
```

May I know what is the equivalent of this in java?

Comment: Please show what you've tried in Java. I'd expect `Long.parseLong(text, 16)` to be fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes I am using this way, but hit `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: `long result = Long.parseUnsignedLong("B62FD56EFD5B375D", 16);` should give you the same result both in java and .net . btw the result you're showing in your post doesn't seem to be what I've getting on JetBrains Rider when i execute the code. I am getting `-5318797962227533987` for both java and c#.

Comment: @Aomine, you can post it, and I will mark it as my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @PanadolChong sure, can do I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Long.parseUnsignedLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseUnsignedLong-java.lang.String-int-) in Java to get the same result.

```
long result = Long.parseUnsignedLong("B62FD56EFD5B375D", 16);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maximum value is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` (inclusive) for a long value. When the value `B62FD56EFD5B375D` parsed it is `13,127,946,111,482,018,682` which is unable to hold in a long value.

So instead use BigInteger.

Answer (score 1):

```
long dec1 = new BigInteger("B62FD56EFD5B375D", 16).longValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with BigInteger

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger(hex, 16);
```